# How to avoid memory allocations in custom Julia iterators?

Tags: debugging, iterator, julia, type-stability

Consider the following Julia "compound" iterator: it merges two iterators, `a` and `b`,
each of which are assumed to be sorted according to `order`, to a single ordered
sequence:

```
struct MergeSorted{T,A,B,O}
    a::A
    b::B
    order::O

    MergeSorted(a::A, b::B, order::O=Base.Order.Forward) where {A,B,O} =
        new{promote_type(eltype(A),eltype(B)),A,B,O}(a, b, order)
end

Base.eltype(::Type{MergeSorted{T,A,B,O}}) where {T,A,B,O} = T

@inline function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T}, 
                      state=(iterate(self.a), iterate(self.b))) where T
    a_result, b_result = state
    if b_result === nothing
        a_result === nothing && return nothing
        a_curr, a_state = a_result
        return T(a_curr), (iterate(self.a, a_state), b_result)
    end

    b_curr, b_state = b_result
    if a_result !== nothing
        a_curr, a_state = a_result
        Base.Order.lt(self.order, a_curr, b_curr) &&
            return T(a_curr), (iterate(self.a, a_state), b_result)
    end
    return T(b_curr), (a_result, iterate(self.b, b_state))
end
```

This code works, but is type-instable since the Julia iteration facilities are inherently so.  For most cases, the compiler can work this out automatically, however, here it does not work: the following test code illustrates that temporaries are created:

```
>>> x = MergeSorted([1,4,5,9,32,44], [0,7,9,24,134]);
>>> sum(x);
>>> @time sum(x);
0.000013 seconds (61 allocations: 2.312 KiB)
```

Note the allocation count.

Is there any way to efficiently debug such situations other than playing around with the code and hoping that the compiler will be able to optimize out the type ambiguities?  Does anyone know there any solution in this specific case that does not create temporaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### How to diagnose the problem?

Answer: use `@code_warntype`

Run:

```
julia> @code_warntype iterate(x, iterate(x)[2])
Variables
  #self#::Core.Const(iterate)
  self::MergeSorted{Int64, Vector{Int64}, Vector{Int64}, Base.Order.ForwardOrdering}
  state::Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
  @_4::Int64
  @_5::Int64
  @_6::Union{}
  @_7::Int64
  b_state::Int64
  b_curr::Int64
  a_state::Int64
  a_curr::Int64
  b_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}
  a_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}

Body::Tuple{Int64, Any}
1 ─       nothing
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(@_4))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(@_5))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(@_6))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(b_state))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(b_curr))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(a_state))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(a_curr))
│   %9  = Base.indexed_iterate(state, 1)::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Int64}, Any[Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Core.Const(2)])
│         (a_result = Core.getfield(%9, 1))
│         (@_7 = Core.getfield(%9, 2))
│   %12 = Base.indexed_iterate(state, 2, @_7::Core.Const(2))::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Int64}, Any[Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Core.Const(3)])
│         (b_result = Core.getfield(%12, 1))
│   %14 = (b_result === Main.nothing)::Core.Const(false)
└──       goto #3 if not %14
2 ─       Core.Const(:(a_result === Main.nothing))
│         Core.Const(:(%16))
│         Core.Const(:(return Main.nothing))
│         Core.Const(:(Base.indexed_iterate(a_result, 1)))
│         Core.Const(:(a_curr = Core.getfield(%19, 1)))
│         Core.Const(:(@_6 = Core.getfield(%19, 2)))
│         Core.Const(:(Base.indexed_iterate(a_result, 2, @_6)))
│         Core.Const(:(a_state = Core.getfield(%22, 1)))
│         Core.Const(:(($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)))(a_curr)))
│         Core.Const(:(Base.getproperty(self, :a)))
│         Core.Const(:(Main.iterate(%25, a_state)))
│         Core.Const(:(Core.tuple(%26, b_result)))
│         Core.Const(:(Core.tuple(%24, %27)))
└──       Core.Const(:(return %28))
3 ┄ %30 = Base.indexed_iterate(b_result, 1)::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(2)])
│         (b_curr = Core.getfield(%30, 1))
│         (@_5 = Core.getfield(%30, 2))
│   %33 = Base.indexed_iterate(b_result, 2, @_5::Core.Const(2))::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(3)])
│         (b_state = Core.getfield(%33, 1))
│   %35 = (a_result !== Main.nothing)::Core.Const(true)
└──       goto #6 if not %35
4 ─ %37 = Base.indexed_iterate(a_result, 1)::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(2)])
│         (a_curr = Core.getfield(%37, 1))
│         (@_4 = Core.getfield(%37, 2))
│   %40 = Base.indexed_iterate(a_result, 2, @_4::Core.Const(2))::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(3)])
│         (a_state = Core.getfield(%40, 1))
│   %42 = Base.Order::Core.Const(Base.Order)
│   %43 = Base.getproperty(%42, :lt)::Core.Const(Base.Order.lt)
│   %44 = Base.getproperty(self, :order)::Core.Const(Base.Order.ForwardOrdering())
│   %45 = a_curr::Int64
│   %46 = (%43)(%44, %45, b_curr)::Bool
└──       goto #6 if not %46
5 ─ %48 = ($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)))(a_curr)::Int64
│   %49 = Base.getproperty(self, :a)::Vector{Int64}
│   %50 = Main.iterate(%49, a_state)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %51 = Core.tuple(%50, b_result)::Tuple{Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %52 = Core.tuple(%48, %51)::Tuple{Int64, Tuple{Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}
└──       return %52
6 ┄ %54 = ($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)))(b_curr)::Int64
│   %55 = a_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}
│   %56 = Base.getproperty(self, :b)::Vector{Int64}
│   %57 = Main.iterate(%56, b_state)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %58 = Core.tuple(%55, %57)::Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}
│   %59 = Core.tuple(%54, %58)::Tuple{Int64, Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}}
└──       return %59
```

and you see that there are too many types of return value, so Julia gives up specializing them (and just assumes the second element of return type is `Any`).

##### How to fix the problem?

Answer: reduce the number of return type options of `iterate`.

Here is a quick write up (I do not claim it is most terse and have not tested it extensively so there might be some bug, but it was simple enough to write quickly using your code to show how one could approach your problem; note that I use special branches when one of the collections is empty as then it should be faster to just iterate one collection):

```
struct MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,F1,F2}
    a::A
    b::B
    order::O
    fa::F1
    fb::F2
    function MergeSorted(a::A, b::B, order::O=Base.Order.Forward) where {A,B,O}
        fa, fb = iterate(a), iterate(b)
        F1 = typeof(fa)
        F2 = typeof(fb)
        new{promote_type(eltype(A),eltype(B)),A,B,O,F1,F2}(a, b, order, fa, fb)
    end
end

Base.eltype(::Type{MergeSorted{T,A,B,O}}) where {T,A,B,O} = T

struct State{Ta, Tb}
    a::Union{Nothing, Ta}
    b::Union{Nothing, Tb}
end

function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,Nothing,Nothing}) where {T,A,B,O}
    return nothing
end

function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,F1,Nothing}) where {T,A,B,O,F1}
    return self.fa
end

function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,F1,Nothing}, state) where {T,A,B,O,F1}
    return iterate(self.a, state)
end

function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,Nothing,F2}) where {T,A,B,O,F2}
    return self.fb
end

function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,Nothing,F2}, state) where {T,A,B,O,F2}
    return iterate(self.b, state)
end

@inline function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,F1,F2}) where {T,A,B,O,F1,F2}
    a_result, b_result = self.fa, self.fb
    return iterate(self, State{F1,F2}(a_result, b_result))
end

@inline function Base.iterate(self::MergeSorted{T,A,B,O,F1,F2}, 
    state::State{F1,F2}) where {T,A,B,O,F1,F2}
    a_result, b_result = state.a, state.b

    if b_result === nothing
        a_result === nothing && return nothing
        a_curr, a_state = a_result
        return T(a_curr), State{F1,F2}(iterate(self.a, a_state), b_result)
    end

    b_curr, b_state = b_result
    if a_result !== nothing
        a_curr, a_state = a_result
        Base.Order.lt(self.order, a_curr, b_curr) &&
            return T(a_curr), State{F1,F2}(iterate(self.a, a_state), b_result)
    end
    return T(b_curr), State{F1,F2}(a_result, iterate(self.b, b_state))
end
```

And now you have:

```
julia> x = MergeSorted([1,4,5,9,32,44], [0,7,9,24,134]);

julia> sum(x)
269

julia> @allocated sum(x)
0

julia> @code_warntype iterate(x, iterate(x)[2])
Variables
  #self#::Core.Const(iterate)
  self::MergeSorted{Int64, Vector{Int64}, Vector{Int64}, Base.Order.ForwardOrdering, Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
  state::State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
  @_4::Int64
  @_5::Int64
  @_6::Int64
  b_state::Int64
  b_curr::Int64
  a_state::Int64
  a_curr::Int64
  b_result::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
  a_result::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}

Body::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}}
1 ─       nothing
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(@_4))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(@_5))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(@_6))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(b_state))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(b_curr))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(a_state))
│         Core.NewvarNode(:(a_curr))
│   %9  = Base.getproperty(state, :a)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %10 = Base.getproperty(state, :b)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│         (a_result = %9)
│         (b_result = %10)
│   %13 = (b_result === Main.nothing)::Bool
└──       goto #5 if not %13
2 ─ %15 = (a_result === Main.nothing)::Bool
└──       goto #4 if not %15
3 ─       return Main.nothing
4 ─ %18 = Base.indexed_iterate(a_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1)::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(2)])
│         (a_curr = Core.getfield(%18, 1))
│         (@_6 = Core.getfield(%18, 2))
│   %21 = Base.indexed_iterate(a_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 2, @_6::Core.Const(2))::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(3)])
│         (a_state = Core.getfield(%21, 1))
│   %23 = ($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)))(a_curr)::Int64
│   %24 = Core.apply_type(Main.State, $(Expr(:static_parameter, 5)), $(Expr(:static_parameter, 6)))::Core.Const(State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}})
│   %25 = Base.getproperty(self, :a)::Vector{Int64}
│   %26 = Main.iterate(%25, a_state)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %27 = (%24)(%26, b_result::Core.Const(nothing))::State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %28 = Core.tuple(%23, %27)::Tuple{Int64, State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}
└──       return %28
5 ─ %30 = Base.indexed_iterate(b_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1)::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(2)])
│         (b_curr = Core.getfield(%30, 1))
│         (@_5 = Core.getfield(%30, 2))
│   %33 = Base.indexed_iterate(b_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 2, @_5::Core.Const(2))::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(3)])
│         (b_state = Core.getfield(%33, 1))
│   %35 = (a_result !== Main.nothing)::Bool
└──       goto #8 if not %35
6 ─ %37 = Base.indexed_iterate(a_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1)::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(2)])
│         (a_curr = Core.getfield(%37, 1))
│         (@_4 = Core.getfield(%37, 2))
│   %40 = Base.indexed_iterate(a_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 2, @_4::Core.Const(2))::Core.PartialStruct(Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Any[Int64, Core.Const(3)])
│         (a_state = Core.getfield(%40, 1))
│   %42 = Base.Order::Core.Const(Base.Order)
│   %43 = Base.getproperty(%42, :lt)::Core.Const(Base.Order.lt)
│   %44 = Base.getproperty(self, :order)::Core.Const(Base.Order.ForwardOrdering())
│   %45 = a_curr::Int64
│   %46 = (%43)(%44, %45, b_curr)::Bool
└──       goto #8 if not %46
7 ─ %48 = ($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)))(a_curr)::Int64
│   %49 = Core.apply_type(Main.State, $(Expr(:static_parameter, 5)), $(Expr(:static_parameter, 6)))::Core.Const(State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}})
│   %50 = Base.getproperty(self, :a)::Vector{Int64}
│   %51 = Main.iterate(%50, a_state)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %52 = (%49)(%51, b_result::Tuple{Int64, Int64})::State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %53 = Core.tuple(%48, %52)::Tuple{Int64, State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}
└──       return %53
8 ┄ %55 = ($(Expr(:static_parameter, 1)))(b_curr)::Int64
│   %56 = Core.apply_type(Main.State, $(Expr(:static_parameter, 5)), $(Expr(:static_parameter, 6)))::Core.Const(State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}})
│   %57 = a_result::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %58 = Base.getproperty(self, :b)::Vector{Int64}
│   %59 = Main.iterate(%58, b_state)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %60 = (%56)(%57, %59)::State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
│   %61 = Core.tuple(%55, %60)::Tuple{Int64, State{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}
└──       return %61
```

EDIT: now I have realized that my implementation is not fully correct, as it assumes that the return value of `iterate` if it is not `nothing` is type stable (which it does not have to be). But if it is not type stable then compiler must allocate. So a fully correct solution would first check if iterate is type stable. If it is - use my solution, and if it is not - use e.g. your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I have to say, I don't find this code particularly pretty, but it seems that's what you have to do ...

Comment: It is not pretty at all unfortunately. Maybe you could change the settings of Julia before compiling it to force it to try to follow the data structures more deeply when compiling code, but this is probably something that is not recommended normally.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! Do you mind if I cross-post this to the Julia Discourse? It seemst there are some Julia core devs lurking there, so someone may have enough compiler-foo to help me...